# Break point not hit in custom installer action using Framework 4.0

Tags: installation, windows-installer, custom-action

I spent hours trying to debug a custom installer dll built using .net framework 4.0, but no matter what I tried the break point would not be hit. I had a similar project in 3.5 and there were not problems hitting the breakpoints using Debugger.Break(). After almost giving up on this, I decided to switch back to 3.5. Immediately I could hit the breakpoints again! So for some reason using 4.0 and trying to hit the debugger does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know why this has been downvoted? It's generally a very bad idea to write custom actions in .NET languages since the dependency needed to run the code might be missing from the target machine.

Having said that, I suppose the breakpoint problem could result if you have no debugging symbols installed for .NET 4.0. I have never faced this, and I am also not sure there are not other causes, but you could try to install the .NET 4.0 SDK instead of the .NET 4.0 runtime only.

I am not sure exactly what setup you should install, but I would look around at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/default.aspx .